# JQuery UI Combobox Disable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I hope this is not a duplicate question. I have searched enough on Stackoverflow to find an answer my simplest question.

I have a set of radiobox and based on the values of the radiobox I need to disable / enable the user from selecting a from combobox.

Whatever I do, I am not able to make the combobox ReadOnly or Disabled. I use the JQueryUI by directly linking it to http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js. The code to make the normal combobox to the jQuery is as follows:-

```
$('#cbCountry").combobox();
```

I tried different methods specified in different places on the net. Nothing seems to work.

Comment: @Yoni : combobox is an extension of autocomplete : http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy modification to combobox library to use:

```
$("#cbCountry").combobox('disable'); 
$("#cbCountry").combobox('enable');
```

In your combobox.js file add:

1. In **_create: function()** add local variable "a" (after *var input, **a**,* ...).
2. Change `input = $("<input>")` to `input = this.input = $("<input>")`.
3. Change `a = $("<a>")` to `a = this.a = $("<a>")`.
4. Insert after *destroy function*:

--

```
disable: function() {
    this.input.prop('disabled',true);
    this.input.autocomplete("disable");
    this.a.button("disable");
},
enable: function() {
    this.input.prop('disabled',false);
    this.input.autocomplete("enable");
    this.a.button("enable");
}
```

Comment: Thankx a lot.. It worked... Thankx a lot. You have solved an issue that I had for months.

Answer (score 0):

I have just checked, and you right, disable a combobox is more complex than we could think.

So, I made a fiddle for you that you can find here : http://jsfiddle.net/S77xa/61/

Comment: Unfortunately that doesnt work.  I am sorry that I am new to JQuery and JQuery UI. And one thing that I can not understand here is the difference between the AutoComplete and the ComboBox.

Comment: combobox is using autocomplete and permit to add a button on the right side of the autocomplete input element. But I don't understand why your elements cannot be disable. Do you have a JS error in the console (F12->console)?

Comment: The Code I use is
<div>        
        Select Option:
        <select id="sl1">
            <option value="1">Option 1</option>
            <option value="2">Option 2</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#sl1").combobox();
            $("#sl1").combobox("option", "disabled", true);
        });
    </script>

Comment: In your case, you REALLY need to use autocomplete function : $('#sl1').autocomplete( "disable" ) even if your object is a combobox

Comment: I checked the Console and I dont see any issues with my page!

Comment: It seems I am doing something wrong. I tried that too and it doesnt work! I have not idea on how to fix this!!!

Answer (score 0):

Boulliou's answer is the better one. Here is another way:

If you do use `$.autocomplete` then:

```
$('#cbCountry").autocomplete( "option", "disabled", true );
```

Comment: That doesnt work. I tried this
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#sl1").combobox();
            $("#sl1").combobox("option", "disabled", true);
        });